# Date is broken after UNION

Tags: mysql, date, laravel-5.1, union-all, laravel-query-builder

I am trying to UNION two queries. Here is my code:

```
public function ledger()
{
    $name = Input::get('client');

    $invoices = DB::table('invoices')
        ->where('client',$name)
        ->selectRaw('`invoiceNumber` as `voucher`,`date`,(`bill` + `ot_bill`) as `amount`');

    $cashIns = DB::table('cash_ins')
        ->where('client',$name)
        ->select('voucher','date','amount')
        ->unionAll($invoices)
        ->get();

    return view('cashIn.ledger',compact('cashIns'));
}
```

But the date is not showing in table. When I check with `dd($cashIns)` all dates are broken or in a different format. I don't understand what has return in date.

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => {#301 ▼
    +"voucher": "JKL02390"
    +"date": b"ß\x07\f\x06"  //it suppose to be 2015-12-06
    +"amount": 23888
  }
  1 => {#304 ▼
    +"voucher": "KL8430"     //it suppose to be 2015-10-07
    +"date": b"""
      ß\x07\n
      \x07
      """
    +"amount": 98392
  }
  2 => {#305 ▼
    +"voucher": "433"
    +"date": b"ß\x07\f\x02"  //it suppose to be 2015-12-02
    +"amount": 9849
  }
]
```

When I individually `dd('invoices')` and `dd('cashIns')` without UNION all dates are well formatted and showing exactly as database.